# UIView shifted up under navigationview controller in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a couple of navigation view controllers linked by modal segues. When I go from one view to another, the next views seem to have the bottom cut off. It seems like the view is shifted down by the size of the navigation bar. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the affected view controller:

```
float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.width, self.view.height - navBarHeight);
```